# Eclipse Error Correct Suggestion Caching

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Galileo working with a large java project.

When I type out a method like:

```
InterfaceDefinedInOtherPackageAndNotYetImported getSomething() {
  return something;
}
```

Eclipse will underline the `InterfaceDefinedInOtherPackageAndNotYetImported` type, because I have not yet imported it.  So I position my cursor on it and press Cntrl + 1 to bring up the list of error fix suggestions.

**Every** single time I do this, I hear my hard disk grinding away, and can see (in Process Explorer) Eclipse doing megabytes of disk I/O.  It takes 5-10 seconds for the suggestion menu to appear.  Even when this is the **very first change** I've made since building.

I'm on a newer, dual-core machine, and can see hundreds of free MB in Eclipse's heap status bar.  So why does Eclipse have to hit the file system each time to get me a list of suggestions?  Can't I get it to cache my type names somehow so that it doesn't have to do this?  How can I get it to go faster?

Comment: Does it behave differently with CTRL+SHIFT+O?

Comment: @Rich: yes, organize imports seems to work significantly faster, though I have a Save Action keeping them cleaned up, so they're never too out of shape.

Answer (score 0):

Is the project small enough to put on a flash drive? You might get a speed boost by moving your workspace to a flash drive or SSD.